# How can I get a random word that starts with a given letter from an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I an array of 20 words in PHP.  Is there a way to extract a random word from this array that starts with a specific letter?

For example if I want a word starting with B say.

```
$arr=array('apple','almond','banana','boat','carrot');
```

Then it will return banana half the time, or boat half the time.

How can I get a random word starting with a given letter from this array?

Comment: You can use in_array() function.

Comment: If the array is hardcoded, then you can group words in array by a letter (e.g. `'b' => array('banana', 'boat')...`) and then just `array_rand($arr[$letter]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. After shuffling the array, each word starting with 'B' or whichever letter will have a random chance of being first in the shuffled array. Relying on PHP's shuffle() is probably more efficient and faster than our own implementation.

```
function returnWithFirstLetter($words, $letter) {
    shuffle($words);
    foreach($words as $word)
        if($word[0] == $letter)
            return $word;
}
```

Comment: Nice! And to clarify, when you run this php function, would this be used like so? returnWithFirstLetter($somearray,"b") ?

Comment: Yup; that's the way to use it

Answer (score 3):

The following works even with methods of selecting eligible words that are more complicate than just "check the first letter" and does not rely on e.g. all eligible words being consecutive in the array.

```
$candidatestested = 0;
foreach ($arr as $candidate) {
   if ($candidate[0] == 'b' && rand(0,$candidatestested++)==0) {
       $result = $candidate;
   }
}
if (!$candidatestested) {
   trigger_error("There was no word matching the criterion");
}
return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty, here you go:

```
function returnRandomWithLetter($words, $letter)
{

    // put all words in different bins, one for each different starting letter
    $bins = array();

    foreach($words as $word)
    {

        $bins[$word[0]][] = $word;

    }

    // return random component from chosen letter's bin 
    return $bins[$letter][array_rand($bins[$letter])];

}
```

Comment: Rather than calling `substr()`, you could directly [access a character position](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) with `$word[0]`.

Comment: @Wiseguy quicker and dirtier, will edit. How couldn't I trust another Charlie Brown!

Comment: Good point, Chuck. If you want quickest and dirtiest, I could answer this question with two lines (possibly one), but at some point it gets more dirty than quick. Readability is still nice sometimes. :-p